# 80s/90s movie: teenagers go inside a crashed asteroid/craft, destroy alien eggs except one, alien parent goes on a rampage looking for its offspring

Tags: story-identification, movie

I hope I'm not mixing up movies I have seen, but I remember seeing some movie when I was a kid. I was born in 1978, so I'm thinking it was an 80s or early 90s movie. I'm from Canada if that helps.

What I kind of remember happening is some asteroid or very vague looking craft crashes to Earth in a small town. Some teenagers find it and go inside. They find some alien eggs and trash/destroy all but one egg.

Some other kid finds the egg and takes it, which then hatches. The kid becomes friends with this alien. Then the parent of the alien goes on a murderous rampage, killing those that destroyed the eggs and trying to find its offspring.

I'm starting to wonder if it was just some weird dream I had or something.

Answer (score 12):

"Extra Terrestrial Visitors" (1983)?

It was sent up on Mystery Science Theater 3000. Did the alien have a long snout?
Here is [a section of review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw1013797/) from [the IMDb page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086026/):

> A small group of dimwitted poachers stumble upon a cache of strange looking eggs stashed in a cave. One of them gets killed by an unseen creature. Then, a young boy with a weird girly voice and a menagerie in his bedroom discovers one of the over-sized eggs and takes it home to hatch it. Meanwhile, the worlds worst rock band decides to go camping in the same woods. When the sluttiest girl in the group runs afoul of both poachers and unseen creatures and takes a plunge off of a cliff, the unmusical losers take refuge in the house of Molly and her - husband? brother? who knows? - and her young son, the same boy who has just hatched an alien creature called Trumpy out of the egg he found in the woods. Trumpy looks like a cross between a plucked turkey and a vacuum cleaner, and does a lot of dippy things like levitating toys and allowing the cat to play with his nose. When people start turning up dead with strange glowy marks upon their foreheads, it seems to be the work of Trumpy. But soon the truth becomes apparent: there is another creature on the loose in the woods, killing anyone who crosses his path.

Comment: Holy Crap! I think that is it. I've been trying to figure what this movie was called for years. I remember being a little freaked out/scared as a kids. Looks like the movie is a little bad by the reviews. Can't wait to watch it again to see just how bad the movie really is and have a good laugh at my younger self. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Amy Glad you found your answer! If you merge your account with the one you used to ask the question by [following the instructions here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), you'll be able to mark this answer as correct by accepting it, which acts as a little extra thank-you for the answerer.